# php - generate pdf with html table and save it on file server

Tags: php, pdf

I am working with a tool which lets user upload a `.csv` file.
That `csv` file contains an address column. I have to use the address from each row in another HTML template. That HTML template is [like this](http://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/US7844553B2/US07844553-20101130-D00000.png) 
.  After creating that template I then need to convert it into a PDF, store the PDF on a file server and give the user a link to the PDF.

I've finished the first two steps - `csv upload` and `created complete template with address`, but I'm stuck on how I can convert a template into a PDF.

I have looked into a few php-pdf libraries like `fpdf` `mpdf`. I'm facing a problem in creating pdf with html template.

Answer (score 0):

A link to a library wich convert HTML to PDF and works pretty well.

First the link to the library

[HTML2PDF](http://www.html2pdf.fr/)

Then some code* to create your PDF using your own generated HTML, where `$content` is your HTML string.

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');
```

*Code taken from the "example page" of the site.

Comment: its working fine, as I have explained I want to convert pdf for each row of `.csv` file ,so instead of displaying pdf i want to create dynamic url of that pdf and store that pdf file on file server

Answer (score 0):

I have used tcpdf in many cases, https://tcpdf.org/
Works well with tables, I have made receipts and accounting related stuff with it. Handle UTF-8 without problems, why it's my way to go.
Only downside is that code is bit long and complicated and it doesn't keep tables as tables in pdf and turns them to divs, so paddings and other styles might be bit trickier to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use webkit based HTML to PDF converter.

Pros are that it is easy to customize and style and to see in the browser how it will look and then you can be sure that it will look as same in PDF as well. You could use CSS and JavaScript as well to style and modify.

Cons are that it is hard to install it on the production server sometimes. But there are web services and APIs that get you covered.

For example one service is https://pdfapi.io. It is free to use. Only when your amounts get bigger, then it will charge like a cup of coffee.

Hope that helps.